# Is this theorem even true?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity, partial-derivative

> A function $f: U\subseteq\mathbb{R^n}\to\mathbb{R^m}$ is continuously differentiable in some open set containing $\vec a$ if and only if all partial derivatives of $f$ are continuous in the same open set.

If yes, can someone help me go about the proof?

Comment: This is wrong.  You may think about the primitive function of the characteristic function of the union of the axes at the origin.

Answer (score 1):

Surely not. How can continuity of partial derivative at a point give differentiability at other points? If all the partial derivatives are continuous throughout the open set then $f$ is continuously differentiable on that open set (and conversely).

Comment: I am sorry, please can you see the edits?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal Your statement is still not correct. See my edited answer.

Comment: Can you give a counter example to prove your assertion and disprove mine

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal You are still assuming continuity of partial derivatives only at one point $a$. This cannot guarantee existence of derivative at other points.

Comment: A counter example is what I am asking for sir.

Comment: Let $f=0$ in a neighborhood of $a$ and any discontinuous function outside that neighborhood.